# MySQL CTE - is it possible to iterate over range of numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I'm curious if is that possible to do similar query using CTE (the values of "id" may vary, not necessarily in succession)

```
SELECT
      elt((@mxId := if(@mxId + 1 <= 3, @mxId + 1, 1)), 5, 10, 22, 33) val,
      id
   FROM my_table
   INNER JOIN (SELECT @mxId := 0) tmp;
```

Expected output:

```
 val | id
-----+----
5    | 1
10   | 2
22   | 3
5    | 4
10   | 5
22   | 6
5    | 7
10   | 8
22   | 9
5    | 10
10   | 11
22   | 12
5    | 13
10   | 14
22   | 15
5    | 16
10   | 17
22   | 18
5    | 19
10   | 20
```

Comment: The values of id may vary?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What is `elt` ?

Comment: [ELT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) returns its Nth argument after the first argument, which is N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with my_table_numbered as (
  select ((row_number() over ())-1)%3 as rn_mod, id from my_table
)
select elt(rn_mod+1, 5, 10, 22, 33) as val, id 
from my_table_numbered;
```

Output:

```
+------+----+
| val  | id |
+------+----+
| 5    |  1 |
| 10   |  2 |
| 22   |  3 |
| 5    |  4 |
| 10   |  6 |
| 22   |  7 |
| 5    |  8 |
| 10   |  9 |
| 22   | 13 |
| 5    | 14 |
| 10   | 15 |
| 22   | 16 |
+------+----+
```

You should specify an ORDER BY in the CTE to get a meaningful and reliable row numbering, but you didn't have one in the query in your question.

Comment: ORDER BY isn't necessary in this case. This query is used to prepare data for further processing by other separate machines - sth like load balancer where "val" is machine number.

thanks again - ((row_number() over ())-1)%3 this saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

```
row_number() OVER ()
```

that's do the magic - Thanks very much